# How User can use Lightning App without Dev console?

Tags: lightning, app

I have created one Lightining App in salesforce, which has few components. How my end User can access this app?

As a developer I can access it from dev console by clicking on Preview Tab.

How I can made it availble for my users?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Hi When you click on Preview button that time the app open in Browser..that time Notice URL And Next time just type URL

Comment: No, I want my user to access my app, they will not remember URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [This link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_lex.htm) states:

First add to your component `<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">` and then:

a. Create a custom tab for this component:

> 1. From Setup, enter Tabs in the Quick Find box, then select Tabs.
> 2. Click New in the Lightning Component Tabs related list.
> 3. 4Select the Lightning component that you want to make available to users.
> 4. Enter a label to display on the tab.
> 5. Select the tab style and click Next.
> 6. When prompted to add the tab to profiles, accept the default and click Save.

b. Add your Lightning components to the App Launcher:

> 1. From Setup, enter Apps in the Quick Find box, then select Apps.
> 2. Click New. Select Custom app and then click Next.
> 3. Enter Lightning for App Labeland click Next.
> 4. In the Available Tabs dropdown menu, select the Lightning Component tab you created and click the right arrow button to add it to the custom app.
> 5. Click Next. Select the Visible checkbox to assign the app to profiles and then Save.

c. Check your output by navigating to the App Launcher in Lightning Experience. Your custom app should appear in the App Launcher. Click the custom app to see the components you added.

Comment: I have followed these steps and made my tab as default for system admin, still I am unable to see tab, I am getting error as below:                                                   URL no longer Exist.  URL is :https://wiptush-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/ValCalHome.cmp?tsid=02u6F000001F1hN                    dont know what is tsid

Comment: Strange, maybe you can try it with a test component that does nothing - just to be sure where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Create VF page in that add Lightning App, Component (Refer [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm))

And Then Make Tab for that VF page.